# Not moving arc / circle? - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
const c = canvas.getContext('2d')

let frameRate = 100

function displayInCanvas() {
    c.beginPath() // keep this

    this.radius = 20
    this.diameter = this.radius * 2
    this.x = canvas.width / 2
    this.y = canvas.height / 2
    this.xVel = 15
    this.yVel = 15

    if (x + diameter >= canvas.width || x <= diameter) {
        xVel = xVel * -1
    }

    c.arc(x, y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2)
    x += xVel
    y += yVel

    c.stroke() // keep this
}

setInterval(function() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth / 1.5 // keep from here to "chicken boy"
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight / 1.5

    canvas.style.position = 'absolute'
    canvas.style.left = '15%'
    canvas.style.top =  '15%'
    displayInCanvas() // chicken boy
}, frameRate)
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have to change,

```
this.xVel = 15;
this.yVel = 15;
```

to make the circle moving.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
const c = canvas.getContext('2d')

let frameRate = 1000 / 60

function displayInCanvas(x, y) {
  c.beginPath() // keep this

  this.radius = 20
  this.diameter = this.radius * 2
  this.x = canvas.width / 2
  this.y = canvas.height / 2
  this.xVel = x
  this.yVel = y

  if (x + diameter >= canvas.width || x <= diameter) {
    xVel = xVel * -1
  }

  c.arc(x, y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2)
  x += xVel
  y += yVel

  c.stroke() // keep this
}

let x = 15;
let y = 15;

setInterval(function() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth / 1.5 // keep from here to "chicken boy"
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight / 1.5

  canvas.style.position = 'absolute'
  canvas.style.left = '15%'
  canvas.style.top = '15%'
  displayInCanvas(x, y) // chicken boy
  x++;
  y++;
}, frameRate)
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas">
```